# run PHP file from shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, shell

I have never added a cron job and am not much use with shell either... 
My chosen cron directory is /etc/cron.daily/

all I need my script to do is run a php file daily. I would be nice if it ran at 11:00 AM.

Is this all I need for the 'script'?:

```
#!/bin/sh
php myphppage.php
```

how (what command) do I 'submit' the script to the cron.daily?

Sincere thanks!

Comment: You don't need a shell script at all. You can just run it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a cron task by yourself instead.

Just type `crontab -e` to edit the crontab and add the following to run your script every days at 11:00 AM :

```
00 11 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Or run your PHP script directly from crontab :

```
00 11 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/myphppage.php
```

Save and exit.

---

If you want to use an external script call (first sample i used with `script.sh`), you should specify full path to binaries/script within your shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /path/to/myphppage.php
```

---

As a side note, using the appropriate [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in your PHP script you don't even need to specify the program to use to run your script.
Add the following at the beginning of your PHP file :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Then your crontab will just look like this :

```
00 11 * * * /path/to/myphppage.php
```

Comment: I am going to update my question with one new thing if that's ok...

Comment: actually figured it out. Thanks again! really appreciate it.

Comment: +1 for shebang syntax